# Can't override a function in posts only

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a blog using the theme [Coral Dark](https://wordpress.org/themes/coral-dark/). This theme has support for post thumbnails, and I want to remove them from the individual posts and leave them everywhere else (home, archives, categories, etc). The thumbnails are created with a pluggable function, so in theory I should just have to override it. If I add this to the functions.php of my child theme:

```
   function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {}
```

The thumbnails effectively disappear. However, if I use a conditional to run the function in posts only:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
   function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {}
}
```

It does nothing. The thumbnails still appear everywhere. I can even replace `is_single` with anything else because WordPress simply ignores it. And if I add a negation to the conditional like this:

```
if ( ! is_single() ) {
   function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {}
}
```

The thumbnails disappear but everywhere. Again, I can replace `is_single` with whatever because the result is the same. I don't understand what's happening.

This is the original function:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'coral_dark_post_thumbnail' ) ) :
/**
 * Displays an optional post thumbnail.
 *
 * Wraps the post thumbnail in an anchor element on index views, or a div
 * element when on single views.
 *
 * Create your own coral_dark_post_thumbnail() function to override in a child theme.
 *
 */
function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {
    if ( post_password_required() || is_attachment() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_singular() ) :
    ?>

    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
    </div><!-- .post-thumbnail -->

    <?php else : ?>

    <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft smallpostthumb', 'alt' => the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), 'sizes' => '(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 210px' ) ); ?>
    </a>

    <?php endif; // End is_singular()
}
endif;
```

Many thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is with the condition. You cannot use condition to wrap your function li

```
if ( is_single() ) {
   function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {}
}
```

Instead use:

```
 function coral_dark_post_thumbnail() {
     if ( is_single() ) {
          //TODO: Something
     }
 }
```

Doing the above should work.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work because the point of the plugged functions is that they don't run if another function with the same name already exists: `if ( ! function_exists( 'coral_dark_post_thumbnail' ) ) :` So if I put the condition within the function, whatever I put within the condition will be irrelevant because the original function will be stopped just for the fact that I'm declaring another one with the same name. That's why I want _to declare it_ (and thus getting overridden) only in individual posts.

Comment: My other option would be to copy/paste the entire original function and put it within the condition, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried doing it the way stated above or not ?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the options I tried before posting my question. :/